# Periodicity of hash functions

Tags: hash, sha

Consider the naive hash function: `HASH = INPUT % 4`. This function is periodic in the sense that if we call it with sequential numbers `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...` the produced hashed sequence will have periodicity of four: `0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, ...`.

My question is whether modern cryptographic hash functions, such as SHA256, are periodic in this sense? In other words, are there some integers `0 <= n` and `0 < k` such that `HASH(n + b) = HASH(n + b + ak)` for all integers `b` in `[0, k - 1]` and all positive integers `a`? For example, will the sequence `SHA256(0), SHA256(1), SHA256(2), SHA256(3), ...` be periodic after some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not. If that was the case it would be trivial to find a collision. The strength of a cryptographic hash function is defined by how hard it is to find Hash(a) == Hash(b). Ideally you need to find all values of Hash(b) to find a collision, which is infeasible if Hash is a lot of bits.

Comment: That's a very good point, thank you. Is this theoretically proven, or only practically so? For example, if `k` and `n` are extremely large (and currently unknown), it would be practically impossible to find collisions, but in theory we could.

Comment: You should ask that on math overflow :) I think if k is finite, you can prove it. But at infinity, with Hash going from a real to a couple of digits I think there actually needs to be a k.

Comment: I might have a sketch that works: You need to show that there exists no k, so that for all a: Hash(a) == Hash (a+k). So, we need to show that there exists one a for every k where Hash(a) != Hash(a+k). Now we require that Hash(x) != Hash(x') if x' is x with exactly one bit flipped. A trivial one bit hash that would do that would be to take all the bits in x and xor them. So to find a for any k just pick a so that a = (a+k) with one bit flipped. That could be a=1<<highestbitindex(k).

Comment: Note how your modulo Hash does not satisfy the single bit flipped property, but I would think real Hash functions do or at least easily could by appending the above one bit hash.